# Get filename from tmpfile() on Windows

Tags: c++, temporary-files

How do I get the filename on Windows from by call to tmpfile() without using tmpnam() instead?

```
std::FILE* tmpf = std::tmpfile();   // Opens a temp file
```

Do it myself

```
const char *name = tmpnam(NULL);  // Get temp name
FILE *fp = fopen(name, "w");      // Create the file
// ...
fclose(fp);
remove(name);
```

Comment: At first glance, if you need the filename it isn't a temp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to convert from `FILE` to `HANDLE`

```
std::FILE* tmpf = std::tmpfile();
HANDLE handle = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(_fileno(tmpf));
```

Then use `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` to obtain the file name (requires Vista or higher)

```
char buf[MAX_PATH];
GetFinalPathNameByHandleA(handle, buf, MAX_PATH, VOLUME_NAME_DOS);
```

Comment: I wish there were a portable way of doing this in standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to generate that filename by yourself - see post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37736406/2338477

But please note also that tmpfile requires administrator privileges to work on some of windows - so using GetFinalPathNameByHandleW is acceptable only if your application is running with administrator priviledges.